# Using facebook sdk 4.4.1. Want to get the number of invites sent by the app user using app invite dialog?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

i want to calculate the number of person app user has invited from his friend list.

this is my code. in result i m getting null.

```
public void openDialogInvite(final Activity activity) {
        String AppURl = "https://fb.me/659724450828700";  //Generated from //fb developers

    //String previewImageUrl = "   ";

    sCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
        AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                .setApplinkUrl(AppURl)
                        //.setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                .build();

        final AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(activity);

        appInviteDialog.registerCallback(sCallbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result) {

                         Log.v("invitation", result.toString());
// setting parameters for request execution for both graph api request
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                        Log.d("Invitation", "Error Occured");
                    }
                });

        appInviteDialog.show(content);
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is not available in the callback then most likely we won't surface this. Why do you need this info? please note that it's against our policies to incentivize invite sends.

Answer (score 1):

It is is not possible, to get the list of invited friends of a user until unless ur app is not a game on canvas.